# Combined cumulative for each row and each column in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I want to add a column in my table, for example to calculate the Combined cumulative :

```
a    b    c    d        newcoulmn
50   0    0    0            50        
0    7    0    0            57
0    0    6    0            63
0    0    0   (4)           59
0    3    0    0            62
0    2    0    0            64
0    0    0   (8)           56
0    0    0   (7)           49
```

Comment: Let's see your attempt....

Comment: @MitchWheat - Nice way to ask *What have you tried?* :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the sum of `a + b + c - d`, then use the window function `ROW_NUMBER()` to calculate the cumulative sum of this value:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT *, a + b + c - d AS abcd,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
  FROM test
)
SELECT c1.a, c1.b, c1.c, c1.d, 
  COALESCE((SELECT SUM(c2.abcd)
            FROM cte AS c2
            WHERE c1.rn >= c2.rn), c1.abcd) AS newcolumn
FROM CTE AS c1;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ba63/16)

This will give you:

```
|  A | B | C | D | NEWCOLUMN |
------------------------------
| 50 | 0 | 0 | 0 |        50 |
|  0 | 7 | 0 | 0 |        57 |
|  0 | 0 | 6 | 0 |        63 |
|  0 | 0 | 0 | 4 |        59 |
|  0 | 3 | 0 | 0 |        62 |
|  0 | 2 | 0 | 0 |        64 |
|  0 | 0 | 0 | 8 |        56 |
|  0 | 0 | 0 | 7 |        49 |
```

---

### Update:

With your query, this can be written like this:

```
WITH YourOriginalQuery
AS
(
    select plitno, A, datils, 0 AS B, 0 AS C, 0 AS D from table1 
    union all 
    select critno, 0, 0, B, 0, 0 from table2 
    union all 
    select klitno, 0, 0, 0, C, 0 from table3 
    union all 
    select bgitno, 0, 0, 0, 0, D from table4
), WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT *, a + b + c - d AS abcd,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rn
  FROM YourOriginalQuery
)
SELECT c1.a, c1.b, c1.c, c1.d, 
  COALESCE((SELECT SUM(c2.abcd)
            FROM cte AS c2
            WHERE c1.rn >= c2.rn), c1.abcd) AS newcolumn
FROM CTE AS c1;
```

Comment: thanks but i want use this statement in my query :select plitno,A,datils,0,0,0
from table1
union all 
select critno,0,0,B,0,0
from table2 
union all
select klitno,0,0,0,C,0
from table3
union all 
select bgitno,0,0,0,0,D
from table4

Comment: WHEN I USE SQL STATEMENT AFTER UPDATE SHOW ME Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near ')'. BUT WHEN I USE THIS STATEMENT BEFORE UPDATE DONT'T SHOW ME ANY PROBLEM PLZ HELP ME & THANKS

Comment: @belalsaeed - Do you want to use this statement to `UPDATE` some fields? IF so, you can use the `CTE`  with `UPDATE`, by updatign it directly, like this `WITH CTE AS ( ... ) UPDATE CTE SET ...`. But you didn't say anything about updating in your question! Please update your question and show me what do you want to do, and the `UPDATE` query you tried, this will ber very helpful to understand what are you trying to do. Thanks.